# Upper bound on finite increment rate for log

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I recently encountered the following inequality : if $a<b$ are two
positive real numbers, then

$$
\frac{\ln(b)-\ln(a)}{b-a} \leq \frac{a+b}{2ab}
$$

This inequality is not very hard to show : if we put
$f(x)=\frac{x^2-a^2}{2ax}-\ln(x)+\ln(a)$, then $f'(x)=\frac{(x-a)^2}{2ax^2}$. I wonder if there are more "geometric" proofs ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is! The average value of the function $\frac1x$ on the interval $[a,b]$ is $\frac{\ln b-\ln a}{b-a}$; the average of the two values at the endpoints, namely $\frac12(\frac1a+\frac1b) = \frac{a+b}{2ab}$, is larger because $\frac1x$ is convex. (Equivalently, the area under the curve itself on $[a,b]$ is smaller than the area under the trapezoid defined by its two endpoints.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not as geometric as you hoped but for $t> 0$ with $\,e^t:=\dfrac ba\;$ (and thus $>1$) we have :
\begin{align}
t&<\sinh(t)\\
2\;\log e^t&<e^t-e^{-t}\\
2\;\log\frac ba&<\frac ba-\frac ab\\
\log b-\log a&<\frac {(b-a)(a+b)}{2ab}\\
\end{align}
(of course Greg Martin's answer is more appropriate here (+1) but I like this interpretation too)